# Is it a good way to program using bash return code?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix

When I automate actions using Bash, I often use the return value of an Unix command to test things like : If a string is present in a file (grep) or if a process is running (ps aux + grep). 

Here is an exemple, grep will return 1 if nothing matches and 0 if there is at least one result.

```
$ ps aux | grep process_that_doesntexist | grep -v grep
$ echo $?
1
$ ps aux | grep init | grep -v grep
root         1  0.0  0.1 135188  6660 ?        Ss   01:43   0:00
$ echo $?
0
```

Is it a bad habit/way of programming ? Should bash scripts written this way should run on production servers ?

Thanks.

Comment: You are using the exit status in exactly the way it is intended to be used.

Comment: @chepner, well -- ideally, one should be directly evaluating it in a conditional rather than referring to `$?`.

Comment: With respect to grepping `ps`, by the way, see also [ProcessManagement](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessManagement), particularly section 3.2 if you're writing software responsible for making sure a service is running -- there are tools specifically built for the purpose built into almost all operating systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grepping through `ps` is not a good practice. Use `pgrep` instead, if your operating system provides it.

However, in general, yes, using exit status to determine whether `grep` has succeeded in matching content is entirely appropriate. That said, instead of referring to `$?`, instead evaluate directly in your conditionals:

```
# When possible, do this:
if grep -q -e value <input; then
  echo "found value" >&2
else
  echo "did not find value" >&2
fi
```

...instead of:

```
# ...not this:
grep -q -e value <input
if [ "$?" -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "found value" >&2
else
  echo "did not find value" >&2
fi
```

This still has the same effect -- `if COMMAND; then ...` checks the exit status of `COMMAND` -- but without an extra layer of indirection.

Comment: Thank, that is kind of answer I was expecting.